# Placing a div below another using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place the (title,meta and content) beside the photo div. using display flex

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0L8C.png)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo"><img src="demo.jpg"></div>
  <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p></div>
  <div class="meta">Apr 7, 2020</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also show your attempts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: .container {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%; }

.photo, .title, .meta, .content {
 width: 50%; }

Comment: Result
Phone     Title
Meta        Content

Answer (score 3):

Set the container css to somthing like:

```
<style>
    .container{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>
```

here you have a great guide to use flex:  [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

- Place 'title', 'meta', 'content' div inside a wrapper.
- So there will be two divs inside the 'container'
- Then give `display: flex` to 'container'.

Your code will be looking like

```html
   <div class="container">
     <div class="photo"><img src="demo.jpg"></div>
     <div>
       <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p></div>
       <div class="meta">Apr 7, 2020</p></div>
       <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p></div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: cannot edit my html, this file is universal on website

Comment: Well this is the simplest approach i can suggest, otherwise there will be workarounds with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is achieved by simply giving the parent element a display of flex. In your case, the parent element is the div with the class of container.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo"><img src="demo.jpg"></div>
  <div class="title"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p></div>
  <div class="meta"><p>Apr 7, 2020</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p></div>
</div>
```

In the .css file, give the .container class a display of flex.

```css
.container {
  display: flex
}
```

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0L8C.png) need this kind of layout